# :include rails mutliple sql statement RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just asked a question about this.. But i now have another question i can't figure out :(
So i have a many_to_many relationship
pages has many groups and groups has many pages. 


`Page.all( :include => :groups, 

          :conditions => ["#{Group.table_name}.id IS NULL AND client_id='#{session[:client_id]}' AND parent_id IS NULL"])`

For some reason this doesn't work. Does anybody know why ?
Removing the #{group.table}.id is NULL works..

I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured is out.. Stupid mistake .. But how often do you write your own SQL? .. NEVER :P 
here it is:

`Page.all(:include => :groups, :conditions => ["#{Group.table_name}.id IS NULL AND #{Page.table_name}.client_id='#{session[:client_id]}' AND #{Page.table_name}.parent_id IS NULL"])`

WHen using an include apparently you need to specify the table name.
:P

Comment: Please no sql-injection code anymore, fix it from `'#{session[:client_id]}'` to `:conditions => ['#{Page.table_name}.client_id = ?', session[:client_id]]`